# How to iterate over an item of objects and array

Tags: php, arrays, json, object, foreach

I do not know how to iterate on this output, it can be simple but try several methods without success.

I have the result of a query that throws a json with objects and fixes, but I can not get the cpu, memory and disk values:

```
<?php
// How to read influx data with curl
$query = urlencode("select * from calls limit 1");
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 1); //timeout in seconds
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"http://127.0.0.1:8086/query?db=myDB&q=$query");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
$res =  json_decode(curl_exec ($ch));
curl_close ($ch);
var_dump($res);
?>
```

and I get this output:

```
{"results":[{"statement_id":0,"series":[{"name":"custom","tags":{"hostname":"LINUX01"},"columns":["time","cpu","mem","load","load"],"values":[["1970-01-01T00:00:00Z",1,78,0,0]]},{"name":"custom","tags":{"hostname":"LINUX02"},"columns":["time","cpu","mem","load","load"],"values":[["1970-01-01T00:00:00Z",6,48,0,0]]},{"name":"custom","tags":{"hostname":"LINUX03"},"columns":["time","cpu","mem","load","load"],"values":[["1970-01-01T00:00:00Z",5,47,0,0]]},{"name":"custom","tags":{"hostname":"LINUX04"},"columns":["time","cpu","mem","load","load"],"values":[["1970-01-01T00:00:00Z",35,94,0,0]]},{"name":"custom","tags":{"hostname":"LINUX05"},"columns":["time","cpu","mem","load","load"],"values":[["1970-01-01T00:00:00Z",3,47,0,0]]},{"name":"custom","tags":{"hostname":"LINUX06"},"columns":["time","cpu","mem","load","load"],"values":[["1970-01-01T00:00:00Z",57,25,0,0]]},{"name":"custom","tags":{"hostname":"LINUX07"},"columns":["time","cpu","mem","load","load"],"values":[["1970-01-01T00:00:00Z",40,47,0,0]]},{"name":"custom","tags":{"hostname":"LINUX08"},"columns":["time","cpu","mem","load","load"],"values":[["1970-01-01T00:00:00Z",41,30,0,0]]},{"name":"custom","tags":{"hostname":"ues90078"},"columns":["time","cpu","mem","load","load"],"values":[["1970-01-01T00:00:00Z",40,20,0,0]]},{"name":"custom","tags":{"hostname":"LINUX09"},"columns":["time","cpu","mem","load","load"],"values":[["1970-01-01T00:00:00Z",33,45,0,0]]},{"name":"custom","tags":{"hostname":"LINUX041"},"columns":["time","cpu","mem","load","load"],"values":[["1970-01-01T00:00:00Z",31,30,0,0]]},{"name":"custom","tags":{"hostname":"LINUX042"},"columns":["time","cpu","mem","load","load"],"values":[["1970-01-01T00:00:00Z",33,8,0,0]]},{"name":"custom","tags":{"hostname":"LINUX043"},"columns":["time","cpu","mem","load","load"],"values":[["1970-01-01T00:00:00Z",54,10,0,0]]}]}]}
```

Try for example:

```
foreach ($res as $test) {
     echo $test->statement_id->cpu;
}
```

I wish I could get this:

```
hostname         time            cpu    mem load    load
linux01   1970-01-01T00:00:00Z    1      78   0       0
```

Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: You should get a _very_ different output because `var_dump` does not output in JSON-Format! Is that a typo in your question or may it be the source of your problem?

Comment: Be careful of being able to send full SQL queries to an web end-point, especially if this is going to be public facing. I would consider creating an API to handle your request, so rather than sending a query string, you send `POST` data in the form of `JSON` or something similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have a difficult time working with this data as is, because most of the data is unkeyed, and that makes it misleading to work with as an object. It would be easier in this case if you worked with the array. You can do this by using true as the second parameter of the decode.

```
$data =  json_decode(curl_exec ($ch), true);

$results = $data['results'];

foreach ($results['series'] as $server) {
    $cpuIndex = array_search('cpu', $server['columns']);
    echo $server['values'][$cpuIndex];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert it to from JSON to an Object or Array.

Here's a common Array situation:

```
$results = json_decode('{"results":[{"statement_id":0,"series":[{"name":"custom","tags":{"hostname":"LINUX01"},"columns":["time","cpu","mem","load","load"],"values":[["1970-01-01T00:00:00Z",1,78,0,0]]},{"name":"custom","tags":{"hostname":"LINUX02"},"columns":["time","cpu","mem","load","load"],"values":[["1970-01-01T00:00:00Z",6,48,0,0]]},{"name":"custom","tags":{"hostname":"LINUX03"},"columns":["time","cpu","mem","load","load"],"values":[["1970-01-01T00:00:00Z",5,47,0,0]]},{"name":"custom","tags":{"hostname":"LINUX04"},"columns":["time","cpu","mem","load","load"],"values":[["1970-01-01T00:00:00Z",35,94,0,0]]},{"name":"custom","tags":{"hostname":"LINUX05"},"columns":["time","cpu","mem","load","load"],"values":[["1970-01-01T00:00:00Z",3,47,0,0]]},{"name":"custom","tags":{"hostname":"LINUX06"},"columns":["time","cpu","mem","load","load"],"values":[["1970-01-01T00:00:00Z",57,25,0,0]]},{"name":"custom","tags":{"hostname":"LINUX07"},"columns":["time","cpu","mem","load","load"],"values":[["1970-01-01T00:00:00Z",40,47,0,0]]},{"name":"custom","tags":{"hostname":"LINUX08"},"columns":["time","cpu","mem","load","load"],"values":[["1970-01-01T00:00:00Z",41,30,0,0]]},{"name":"custom","tags":{"hostname":"ues90078"},"columns":["time","cpu","mem","load","load"],"values":[["1970-01-01T00:00:00Z",40,20,0,0]]},{"name":"custom","tags":{"hostname":"LINUX09"},"columns":["time","cpu","mem","load","load"],"values":[["1970-01-01T00:00:00Z",33,45,0,0]]},{"name":"custom","tags":{"hostname":"LINUX041"},"columns":["time","cpu","mem","load","load"],"values":[["1970-01-01T00:00:00Z",31,30,0,0]]},{"name":"custom","tags":{"hostname":"LINUX042"},"columns":["time","cpu","mem","load","load"],"values":[["1970-01-01T00:00:00Z",33,8,0,0]]},{"name":"custom","tags":{"hostname":"LINUX043"},"columns":["time","cpu","mem","load","load"],"values":[["1970-01-01T00:00:00Z",54,10,0,0]]}]}]}', true);

foreach ($results["results"][0]["series"] as $array) {

  echo "<table>";
  echo "<thead>";

  echo "<tr>";
  foreach ($array["columns"] as $value) {
    echo "<th>{$value}</th>";
  }
  echo "</tr>";

  echo "</thead>";
  echo "<tbody>";

  echo "<tr>";
  foreach ($array["values"][0] as $value) {
    echo "<td>{$value}</td>";
  }
  echo "</tr>";

  echo "</tbody>";
  echo "<table>";

}
```

If you want something specific:

```
foreach ($results["results"][0]["series"] as $array) {

  foreach ($array["columns"] as $key => $value) {
    if ($value === "cpu") $column = $key;
  }

  echo "cpu: {$array["values"][0][$column]}.<br>";

}
```

To add hostname, simple add:

```
echo "<tr>";
echo "<th colspan=" . count($array["columns"]) . ">{$array["tags"]["hostname"]}</th>";
echo "</tr>";
```

after `echo "<thead>";`.

Comment: Cool! This works. Thank you.
If I want to also show the hostname, something like this:                                                                  
 hostname    time    cpu   mem load load                                                                               
 linux01    1970-01-01T00:00:00Z 1 78 0 0

Comment: Added some more info to the answer.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks, I already have more notion about the handling of json and fixes.
The answer works perfectly.